# What is the most efficient way to display an excel file in a php page, with the options to query and edit?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm not a developer, I'm a student and I need to do what I said above.
Create a web page where you can query and edit an excel file that will have warped on localhost.

PD: I'm from Venezuela and I do not know English, I'm helping with the Google translator

Comment: You will probably want to use a library like [PHPOffice/PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Comment: If I'm thinking of using NotePad++, Wamp and phpexcel libraries.